# Scroll to top of element on short page

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

I am trying to scroll my page (on click) to the top of en element. The problem here is that my page is to short to scroll to the top of the element. IS this possible?

Here's my code

```
$('.x-class').on('click', function(e) {
    moveWindowTo($('.yclass').eq(0));
});

function moveWindowTo($target) {
  $('body,html').animate({ scrollTop: $target.offset().top }, 'slow');
}
```

Comment: Unless until you are not getting a scrollbar, you can't get this worked.

Comment: So, there is no other way?

Comment: Do you see a scrollbar in your page?

Comment: No, but there has to be a way to let the page grow with it I think?

Comment: Does it work with `0` instead of `$target.offset().top` ?

Comment: No that doesn't work either

Comment: It is hard to guess... Can you open a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), so we can test and help better?

Comment: No , no errors. The animate works fine, it just stops to soon because of the short page

Comment: @SaraBarreraRiano, Either you need to fill the page with some contents or you will have to increase the height of your page (which is not recommended and will be looking very odd)

Comment: Is that the only solution? There isn't a way to let the page grow if it needs to?

Comment: @SaraBarreraRiano My answer works, if there's a scrollbar present. If there isn't one, obviously it can't scroll as there's nowhere to scroll. Should the page dynamically become long enough that a scrollbar appears, the answer will work.

Comment: if the height of the page is that short that you don't have a scrollbar , why would you want to scroll to an element on click ?

best to share the full code ( html mostly ) so we can help you better

Answer (score 0):

This code uses .parent() to scroll up to the top of the containing div:

```
$('.x-class').on('click', function(e) {
  moveWindowTo($(this).eq(0));
});

function moveWindowTo(target) {
  $('body,html').animate({
    scrollTop: target.parent().offset().top
  }, 'slow');
}
```

Here is a working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9ndyLLz7/). Scrolling down and clicking the red box will scroll it to the top of the containing div.

Comment: Well this isn't quite usable in my case. Your page has whitespace beneath the last element, that's why you can scroll the the top of it.

Comment: I added all of the white space to show the scrolling capability. Like others have said, you need a scroll bar in order to have something to scroll to. If you can post more of your code that would help us all out.